# Parsing files and replacing matching entries based on single element

Tags: bash, powershell

I come to you in a time of great need.
My input files have structure like this:

File1

```
2   "Key1"   "ContentAASD#@!"   |
3   "Key2"   "Conte111111#@!"   |
4   "Key112"   "Keep me"   |
```

File2

```
2   "Key1"   "I'm correct one"   |
3   "Key2"   "Me too"   |
```

My desired output would be to replace content of 3rd element: "**ContentAASD#@!**" to "**I'm correct one**" if 2nd element "**Key1**" is the same between files, if it's not it should be ignored.

To sums it up that would be the output after running script:

```
2   "Key1"   "I'm correct one"   |
3   "Key2"   "Me too"   |
4   "Key112"   "Keep me"   |
```

Between double quotations, there might be a lot of spaces, special characters and so on and they should be preserved.

I hope that I explained this well enough.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Gonna need to know the specifics of your problem, but if the following conditions are met: 1) Keys in File2 are assumed to be a subset of File1, and 2) the order of the output doesn't matter (or you can re-sort based on that first column), then you can convert File2 into a list of regex's, pass them to grep -v to eliminate lines which match any of them from File1, then concatenate the result with File2.

Comment: To be more precise File1 will be my final output file.
So if my understanding is correct I need to loop through each line of File1 and compare the 2nd column. If values from them match I need to replace the content of 3rd column in File1 with the content of 3rd column that's in File2.

File2 is source of truth for File1 when it comes to 3rd column.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've attempted and the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: why have you tagged the question with `bash` and `powershell`? which one are you actually using?

Comment: for matching rows will the first column also match and if not, which would be used in the final output; for example assume `8 "Key5"` and `10 "Key5"` ... keep the `8` or the `10`?

Comment: please update the question to describe the field delimiter for both files; a tab? 3 spaces? something else?

Comment: @skwierczyk1 The solution I have in mind requires no loops, because you can create a file with many regex's and pass them to grep in a single call. But first you need to explain your problem more formally: are the assumptions I made valid, what's that `|` at the end of each line, what characters can each field contain (could keys also have weird characters?), are fields always quoted, what is this file format, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any `awk` (which is the mandatory POSIX tool you would use if you wanted to do this in `bash`):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} NR==FNR{a[$2]=$4; next} $2 in a{$4=a[$2]} 1' file2 file1
2   "Key1"   "I'm correct one"   |
3   "Key2"   "Me too"   |
4   "Key112"   "Keep me"   |
```

That will work as long as you don't have escaped double quotes or newlines inside your double quoted fields, which presumably you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution (loosely based on the `bash` tag on the question):

0. Read `File2` into an associative array with the obvious meaning of keys and values. (You can use `"` as an `IFS` and parse lines to isolate keys and values. A more sophisticated approach will be needed in case there are escape sequences.)
1. Read `File1` the same way you read `File2`, but instead of adding its data into an associative array, only parse out its keys and values and search for each key in the associative array containing `File2` data.

   - If there’s a match, replace the old value from `File1` by the new value from `File2` found in the associative array under the same key. Print out the modified line.
   - If there’s no match, just print out the original line from `File1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that may possibly work (based on the `PowerShell` tag on the question), and similar to the `bash` solution above:

```
$file1 = Get-Content -Path "[PATH]\file1.txt" 
$file2 = Get-Content -Path "[PATH]\file2.txt"

    for($i=0;$i -lt $file1.count;$i++){
        $key_file1 = ($file1[$i] | Select-String -Pattern 'Key\d+').Matches.Value
        $key_file2 = ($file2[$i] | Select-String -Pattern 'Key\d+').Matches.Value
        
        if($key_file1 -eq $key_file2){
            $file2[$i] | Out-File -FilePath "[PATH]\file3.txt" -Append
        }
        else{
            $file1[$i] | Out-File -FilePath "[PATH]\file3.txt" -Append
        }
    }
# Comment out below if you want to view before replacing your file 1
Copy-Item -Path "[PATH]\file3.txt" -Destination "[PATH]\file1.txt"
Remove-Item -Path "[PATH]\file3.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell solution using [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Compare-Object) (and [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) to read the files line by line):

```
Compare-Object -PassThru -IncludeEqual `
  -ReferenceObject  (Get-Content file2) `
  -DifferenceObject (Get-Content file1) `
  -Property         { ($_ -split '"')[1] }
```

- `-Property { ($_ -split '"')[1] }` compares the lines of the two files by the 2nd (`[1]`) token that results from splitting the lines into tokens by `"`, using `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split).
- `-IncludeEqual` also includes lines that compare as *equal* (by default, `Compare-Object` only outputs elements of the input collections that *differ*).
- `-PassThru` passes the input objects (lines) through as-is; in the case of lines that compare as *equal*, the line from the `-ReferenceObject` collection is passed through, which is why it is `file2`'s lines that are passed to `-ReferenceObject`, so that they replace the matching `file1` lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mawk 'BEGIN { ___ = (_+= _^= FS = OFS = "\42") + _ 

 } NR == FNR ? (__[$_] = $___)(NF = !_) : ! ($_ in __) || $___ = __[$_]'

            <( printf '%s' '
                        2   "Key1"   "I'\''m correct one"   |
                        3   "Key2"   "Me too"   |'          ) 

            <( printf '%s' '
                        2   "Key1"   "ContentAASD#@"   |
                        3   "Key2"   "Conte111111#@\!"   |
                        4   "Key112"   "Keep me"   |'       )
```

---

```
1   2   "Key1"   "I'm correct one"
2   3   "Key2"   "Me too"   |
3   4   "Key112"   "Keep me"   |
```

Comment: Given that an `awk`-based answer was accepted that is both more concise and less obscure than yours (even though the former could use an explanation too), I'm curious as to what you think your answer has to offer.

Comment: @mklement0 : what it offers is the bypassing of unnecessary action blocks and statements like `next` or the superfluous `} 1` at the tail end that could easily be incorporated into the pattern logic, as illustrated. Just because they call it a `"pattern space"` doesn't mean you couldn't also use it to perform the associated actions right there. Heck, you could even `getline` right in the pattern space if you like.

Comment: I encourage you to add this information _to your answer_, along with an explanation of why bypassing unnecessary constructs results in a more verbose solution.  I also encourage you to explain why you're using `mawk`, which cannot be expected to present on all Unix-like platforms by default.

Comment: @mklement0 : you can do things the "idiomatic" way, or you can do it the elegant and efficient way. like this function i conjured up recently : `function julian_by_monthend(__, _) { return ( (_ = !!+_ || _~"^[Yy]") - ((__+= ( __ %= (_+=_^=_) * (_ += _ + _)) <= -__ ? _ + _ : !_ ) <= _)) ^ (!!_ < __) + __ *_*--_ + int(__*_/ (++_ + _)) }` :: instead of having to hard code the 24 cumulative julian(ordinal) days by month ends (leap + common), I realized a formulaic approach can calculate it all. Is it idiotmatic? absolutely not. Does it work ? Sure works better than hard coding anything

Comment: @mklement0 : cuz my stupid mac defaults `awk` to the ultra ghetto `nawk` that doesn't even know how to handle `\0` null bytes. it's just what i use the most, but that same code works for any `POSIX` compliant awk. heck u can use `bwk` if u like. As for verbosity, I think you're confounding others not having spaces between things as being succinct and concise. As for that julian thing, it also has efficient recycling of variables, so I didn't need any extra ones other than the bare minimum for accepting input - the month number, and the leap-year indicator.

Comment: I'll take your word that what you're showing is elegant and efficient - _personally_, the wall of `_`s makes me not even want to investigate the claim, because, even if I can eventually wrap my head around it,  I wouldn't consider such solutions maintainable. However, to increase the chance that _others_ see value in your solution, let me again suggest that you _update your answer_ to state your case.

Comment: @mklement0 : so often people have to hard-code in constants, then also have separate code to input sanitization checks. That would be the idiomatic way . my approach is to combine them, as sanitize input on the way to generate the needed constants on the fly. Do you see a single hard coded number in my function ?

Comment: @mklement0 : It's not a popularity contest. If they like other entries more then so be it

Comment: Indeed it isn't, and I never suggested it was. I was just offering you a perspective on (a) why at least _one_ user (read: I) is disinclined to even spend time investigating your solution based on the answer in its present form (my _hunch_ is that I'm not the only one), and (b) how you might improve your answer to get (more) future readers to see the merit of your solution.